# Flatten Observable<Observable<Object[]>>

Tags: asynchronous, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I'm trying to create a join in Firebase.

So, I asynchronously get array of ids from the db, and for each id I then asynchronously load the actual object. And the function is supposed to return Observable

Thus, with the first async request I'm getting the Observable (string is the id). 
So, whatever I tried here I either get Observable or some other stuff that is not what I want to get.

The code:

```js
getUserFavourites(userId = ""):Observable<any[]> {
  return this.af.database.list('/ranks_by_user/likes/'+userId, {
    query: {
      orderByKey: true,
      limitToFirst: 50
    }
  }).flatMap( (likes:any[]) => {
    return like.map(like => {
      return this.af.database.object("/citations/" + like.$key)
    });
  });
}
```

And the error is:

> `Type 'Observable<FirebaseObjectObservable<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.`

Comment: Can you include your code in the question?

Comment: Updated with the code

Comment: You would need to include the code for `Citation`. Is is an interface or a class? If it's a class, at the very least you'd need to indicate what parameters the constructor takes.

Comment: It's a class. But there is nothing class-specific going on here. It could easily be type of "any". I just pasted the code as is. Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to obtain an array of citations. Note that the `first` operator is used to obtain the current value from the `object` observables, as `forkJoin` requires the observables to complete:

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin";
import "rxjs/add/operator/first";
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";

getUserFavourites(userId): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.af.database.list('/ranks_by_user/likes/' + userId, {
    query: {
      orderByKey: true,
      limitToFirst: 50
    }
  })
  .switchMap((likes: any[]) => Observable.forkJoin(
    likes.map(like => this.af.database.object("/citations/" + like.$key).first())
  ));
}
```

`forkJoin` takes an array of observables and returns an observable that emits an array of the observable's final values.

If you were to return `Citation` instances, you would need to create them (presumably, using the values from the database). You could use the `map` operator to do that:

```ts
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
...
likes.map(like => this.af.database.object("/citations/" + like.$key).first().map(value => new Citation(value)))
...
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Works as expected